# How can I change an ng-repeat variable after a response from a socket

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi guys I have this simple bit of Angular:

```
app.controller('FriendsController', ['$scope', 'Page', 'Title', '$http', function($scope, Page, Title, $http) {

  $http.get('/friends')
  .success(function(data) {
    $scope.friends = data.data;
  })
  socket.on('friendslist', function(resp) {
    // Socket was emitted that a user was updated, they are now either Offline or Online
    // So find the proper element and update them to the new value
    if (resp.verb === "updated") {
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.friends; i++) {
        if ($scope.friends[i].id === resp.id) {
          $scope.friends[i].online = resp.data.online;
        }
      }

      //var $friendEl = $('i').find('[data-id="1"]').first();
      //console.log($friendEl);
      //
    }
  });

}]);
```

I'm getting the data to the client side just fine after the socket is emitted, but it doesn't seem to update the value if I `console.log(resp)` it returns the data needed, but when I `console.log($scope.friends[i])` after it updates it still says whatever it was initialized with like the for loop is not finding it and updating it, but I know that it is. Any information would be great thanks.

Comment: I think it you might need to add `.length` to `$scope.friends` in the for loop, so it will read `for (var i = 0; i < $scope.friends.length; i++) {`

Comment: Add a `$scope.$apply()` to tell angular the scope has been changed. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722737/angular-js-socket-io-event-updates-model-not-view (and several other questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be $scope.friends.length in forloop?